# I cannot use npm start to start an express server on windows

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I am new to node. I am trying to run an express server. I get no errors when installing express but when i run `npm start` or `node app` (as all the beginner tutorials point) nothing seems to be happening. The only way i can start the server is by typing `node /bin/www`. My operating system is Windows. Any advice?

Comment: Did you create an `app.js` file containing your code, and then do `> node app.js` on the command line.

Comment: I run `express myapp` just after i installed express and it created `app.js` automatically. `node app.js` just outputs a blank line and then it promts me to my working directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue by changing the code page of cmd-dos. By using `chcp 850 or chcp 65001` in cmd thus changing codepage to latin - utf8 the issue is gone.

Answer (score 2):

The Express scaffold script generates a package.json file with a start script field that points to the app.js file it also created. Since Express 4 was released the scaffold generator script has been moved to its own package. https://github.com/expressjs/generator

All `npm start` does is look in the package.json file for a starting script to pass to node. You can see this in [the documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json.html#default-values).

Running `npm start` with a package.json like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "app.js"
}
```

Is exactly equivalent to running `node app.js`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Alex. I think i get how this all works. I was just curious to see why i can't start the server by running `npm start` or `node app.js` as it is expected following the logic of the code. Maybe i have messed up with node.js installation. But is seemed pretty straightforward. I installed the windows version (automatically added the PATH variable), checked it was installed (`node -v`),installed express globally, run `express myapp` and then `npm start`, which seemed to run `node ./bin/www` but then immediately prompted me to my working directory.